# Hibernate @OneToMany relationship is not fetched properly

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

I have a one to many relationship between entities.
The first entity:

```
@Entity
@NoArgsConstructor
@Getter 
@Setter 
public class Cocktail {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(generator = "uuid")
    @GenericGenerator(
        name = "uuid",
        strategy = "uuid2",
        parameters = {
            @Parameter(
                name = "uuid_gen_strategy_class",
                value = "org.hibernate.id.uuid.CustomVersionOneStrategy"
            )
        }
    )
    private UUID id;
    
    private String image;
    
    @OneToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "name_id")
    private Label labelName;
    
    @OneToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "description_id")
    private Label labelDescription;
    
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "cocktail", fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    private List<CocktailIngredient> cocktailIngredients = new ArrayList<>();
}
```

The second entity:

```
@Entity
@NoArgsConstructor
@Getter @Setter
public class CocktailIngredient {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(generator = "uuid")
    @GenericGenerator(
        name = "uuid",
        strategy = "uuid2",
        parameters = {
            @Parameter(
                name = "uuid_gen_strategy_class",
                value = "org.hibernate.id.uuid.CustomVersionOneStrategy"
            )
        }
    )
    private UUID id;
    
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinColumn(name = "cocktail_id")
    private Cocktail cocktail;
    
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinColumn(name = "ingredient_id")
    private Ingredient ingredient;
    
    private BigDecimal quantity;
}
```

And the Spring Data repository that is loading them:

```
@Repository
public interface CocktailRepository extends JpaRepository<Cocktail, UUID>, CocktailRepositoryCustom {
}
```

The other related code is irrelevant to the question.
The problem is when I call the standard findAll method of CocktailRepository, the list of CocktailRepository in Cocktail is not populated, although Hibernate is querying the related entities from the database (one of the generated queries):

```
Hibernate: 
    select
        cocktailin0_.cocktail_id as cocktail3_1_0_,
        cocktailin0_.id as id1_1_0_,
        cocktailin0_.id as id1_1_1_,
        cocktailin0_.cocktail_id as cocktail3_1_1_,
        cocktailin0_.ingredient_id as ingredie4_1_1_,
        cocktailin0_.quantity as quantity2_1_1_,
        ingredient1_.id as id1_2_2_,
        ingredient1_.alc as alc2_2_2_,
        ingredient1_.description_id as descript4_2_2_,
        ingredient1_.name_id as name_id5_2_2_,
        ingredient1_.unit as unit3_2_2_,
        label2_.id as id1_3_3_,
        label2_.label_en as label_en2_3_3_,
        label2_.label_ru as label_ru3_3_3_,
        label3_.id as id1_3_4_,
        label3_.label_en as label_en2_3_4_,
        label3_.label_ru as label_ru3_3_4_ 
    from
        cocktail_ingredient cocktailin0_ 
    left outer join
        ingredient ingredient1_ 
            on cocktailin0_.ingredient_id=ingredient1_.id 
    left outer join
        label label2_ 
            on ingredient1_.description_id=label2_.id 
    left outer join
        label label3_ 
            on ingredient1_.name_id=label3_.id 
    where
        cocktailin0_.cocktail_id=?
```

So the entity collection is fetched but somewhy not assigned to the field in Cocktail. The JPA provider used is Hibernate. I've tried debugging and what I've seen is that the collection is not populated inside Hibernate classes, so Spring Data is not to blame here. All the code examples I've seen state that the code like this must work, but it's not. What's wrong?

UPDATE:

The result of the query in JSON from the REST Controller built on top of this code:

```
[
    {
        "id": "32616534-3832-3763-2d39-3332322d3131",
        "image": "https://top10a.ru/wp-content/uploads/2019/06/3-8.jpg",
        "labelDTOName": {
            "id": "a2b851d8-9094-11ec-96e5-fcaa14ac5ccc",
            "labelEn": "Mojito",
            "labelRu": "Мохито"
        },
        "labelDTODescription": {
            "id": "ba2083f5-931e-11ec-96e5-fcaa14ac5ccc",
            "labelEn": "",
            "labelRu": ""
        },
        "cocktailIngredientsDTO": []
    }
]
```

As you can see, the cocktailIngredientsDTO collection is empty, while it must be full.

UPDATE 2:
What if I say that the database table is created this way:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `cocktails`.`cocktail` (
  `id` CHAR(36) NOT NULL,
  `image` TINYTEXT NULL,
  `name_id` CHAR(36) NOT NULL,
  `description_id` CHAR(36) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  INDEX `fk_cocktail_label1_idx` (`name_id` ASC) VISIBLE,
  UNIQUE INDEX `name_id_UNIQUE` (`name_id` ASC) VISIBLE,
  INDEX `fk_cocktail_label2_idx` (`description_id` ASC) VISIBLE,
  UNIQUE INDEX `description_id_UNIQUE` (`description_id` ASC) VISIBLE,
  CONSTRAINT `fk_cocktail_label1`
    FOREIGN KEY (`name_id`)
    REFERENCES `cocktails`.`label` (`id`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
  CONSTRAINT `fk_cocktail_label2`
    FOREIGN KEY (`description_id`)
    REFERENCES `cocktails`.`label` (`id`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
ENGINE = InnoDB;
```

UPDATE 3:
Still no answer. The very proof that Stackoverflow is often useless for complicated issues.

Comment: Can you show converter ?

Comment: You mean the converter to DTO? It's irrelevant here because I checked the value of the collection field in the debugger before the Cocktail object reaches the converter and it was already empty. Actually the output of cocktail.getCocktailIngredients() was an empty collection.

Answer (score 0):

Please try removing assignment of empty list:

```
 cocktailIngredients = new ArrayList<>();
```

Just keep cocktailIngredients uninitialized. Setter will do the assignment.

Comment: I've tried that before. It doesn't change anything.